# How to manage user session in React Native?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I'm learning React Native with React Navigation and GraphQL written in TypeScript. I will use Facebook Login for users to register (with Passport.js or Auth0)

How do I manage user session in React Native? Do I need to use Redux?

Please enlighten me.

Comment: There is a great knowledge about it please [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806512/best-way-to-store-global-data-in-asyncstorage-or-redux)

Answer (score 6):

Because session usually contains sensitive info, I would advise avoiding using `AsyncStorage` or similar solution.

Use **more secure approach** with [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain). It will store the session on secure storage.

Sample Code

```
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain';

// When you want to store the session
const rawValue = JSON.stringify(session);
await Keychain.setGenericPassword('session', rawValue);

// When you want to retrieve the session
const credential = await Keychain.getGenericPassword();
const session = JSON.parse(credential.password)
```

Comment: Since [AsyncStortage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) is removed from core React-Native. This approach would be better in security concerned apps.

Comment: Would you also recommend it for `JWT`?

Comment: @Rario yes, I store my JWT token with above method.

Answer (score 1):

You can save user session(data) using AsyncStorage . Please try this library [async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) as recommended By React Native [Website](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage)

**Store data**

```
storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', 'stored value')
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

**Read data**

```
getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

Comment: Am new to react native, how do you import or add the library dependency in a react native project

Comment: just run npm install 'Library-name' OR
yarn add 'Library-name' to install any dependency or Library

Answer (score 0):

you can add user session in redux and persist your redux data with redux-persist.

so add user session info to api call header each time when you call remote endpoint